# Can't use method and confirm attributes on custom helper to create link with icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created the following custom helpers to add links with icons:

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def link_with_icon_to(label, icon, url, data = {}, method = nil)
        render "shared/link_with_icon", label: label, icon: icon, url: url, data: data, method: method
    end

    def edit_link(url)
        link_with_icon_to 'Editar', 'fa fa-pencil', url
    end

    def remove_link(url)
        link_with_icon_to 'Excluir', 'fa fa-trash', url, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
    end
end
```

_link_with_icon.html.erb

```
<%= link_to url, method: method, data: data do %>
    <i class="<%= icon %>" /><span><%= label.html_safe %></span>
<% end %>
```

And I'm using them this way:

```
<% @insurance_companies.each do |insurance_company| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= insurance_company.name %></td>
              <td><%= insurance_company.cnpj %></td>
              <td><%= edit_link edit_insurance_company_path(insurance_company) %></td>
              </td>
              <td><%= remove_link insurance_company %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
```

However the `remove_link` helper is not working. The confirmation is not displayed and the data is not deleted.

What is wrong with my helper?

Comment: Any other tip to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible because you're not passing down the additional options(data and method) to the link_to.

Can't immediately confirm/verify this, but I think a way you can work around this is:

```
def link_with_icon_to(label, icon, url, opts = {})
    render "shared/link_with_icon", label: label, icon: icon, url: url, opts: opts
 # there definitely better ways of handling this, but can't think of another right now
end

# _link_with_icon.html.erb
# spread the opts hash here. the opts hash could be {data: {element: 'whatever'}, method: :delete} etc.
<%= link_to url, **opts do %>
    <i class="<%= icon %>" /><span><%= label.html_safe %></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I updated the code with the missing attributes on helper class and partial, then I got `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` on the partial.